# Asp.Net MVC Consuming a web api from a Class Library

Tags: asp.net-mvc, plugins, asp.net-web-api, class-library

I am wondering if there is a way to create a class library that contains web API, so I can use the dll as a plug-in, to inject into the MVC application.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Google seems to be working just fine: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: Perhaps you just want to keep your asp.net mvc controllers and webapi controllers apart? Then check this so post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677745/mixing-web-api-and-asp-net-mvc-pages-in-one-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could Self-Host a Web API:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/self-host-a-web-api

You can put all your controllers in a Class Library project.

Then use Autofac to resolve the dependencies in your host project:
https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WebApiIntegration

Answer (score 1):

Web API methods are called over HTTP, so calling a Web API service requires it to be hosted somewhere and called using a suitable client as detailed in [@David's link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client). You *can* [self-host Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/self-host-a-web-api), so in theory you could have an assembly local to an MVC application which contained a class which set up and then called a self-hosted Web API service.

You would inject the Web API service behind an interface, something like this:

```
public interface IProductsService
{
    IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts();
}
```

...implemented something like this:

```
public class SelfHostedWebApiProductsService
{
    public SelfHostedWebApiProductsService()
    {
        // Set up a self-hosted Web API service
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        // Call your self-hosted WebApi to get the products
    }
}
```

[Configure your DI container](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=786) to use `SelfHostedWebApiProductsService` for the `IProductsService` interface, and away you go. [This article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/self-host-a-web-api) details how to set up and call a self-hosted Web API.

As the `SelfHostedWebApiProductsService` sets up the self-hosted Web API in its constructor - a relatively expensive operation - you might want to consider giving this class a singleton lifetime in your DI container.