# MVC4 - WebApi - Implementation as part of existing MVC4 Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am new to MVC4 - WebApi. I am just thinking of implementing WebApi in my existing MVC Application.

In the Existing MVC4Application I would like to add Controller Class which derives from ApiController class.  This new controller actions will be called across all the pages to return data.
Is that possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible. A similar question has already been here on SO and you only need to change the namespace of your api controller class to keep them separate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677745/mixing-web-api-and-asp-net-mvc-pages-in-one-project