# How to structure my MVC Web API application with AngularJS without having naming conflict

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, directory-structure

I want to start with an MVC4 application using the API controller and AngularJS. But I am not really sure how to structure my applicaton.

Suppose I start out with a normal `controller` that is called `UserController`. This controller has an `Index` action and returns a (razor) view.

In that view I will be doing some HTML and AngularJS things. The angular code will in return call an API controller to get its JSON data.

But this is the part that puzzles me. I already have a `UserController` that returns the view. But then I also need another `UserController` (that extends the `ApiController`) to return JSON data, right?

So I need an API controller to `GET` user data and `PUT` user data etc. So a logical name for that would be `UserController` as well.

But obviously I cannot have two controllers with the same name. So how does this work? How should i name/structure my MVC application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mixing Web Api and ASP.Net MVC Pages in One Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677745/mixing-web-api-and-asp-net-mvc-pages-in-one-project)

Comment: use the same class name in separate namespaces

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your Controllers in a Controllers folder and Your ApiControllers in an ApiControllers folder in your project.  That's what I do.

```
MyProject
 |
 ---ApiControllers
 |   |
 |   ---UserController.cs
 |
 ---Controllers
     |
     ---UserController.cs
```

The namespaces will be different by default if you do this, permitting you to share class names.

And then for the routing one will be `api/user` and the other `user`.