# Connect to an MVC application from a winforms application

Tags: c#, database, winforms, asp.net-mvc-4, actionresult

I have written a C# MVC4 internet application and have a question in relation to calling some of the `ActionResult` methods.

How can I call any of the `ActionResult` methods from a different application other than the MVC application?

What I am wanting to do is create a Winforms application, connect to the MVC application and then call some of the `ActionResult` methods.

Is this possible? How should I do this? What resources should I research into?

Thanks in advance

Comment: All you need is to make web requests. Look into using the `WebClient` for simple requests like this.

Comment: Will the WebClient work when sending objects to MVC methods?

Comment: Of course: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploaddata.aspx

Comment: Depending on whether your MVC app is RESTful, you might want to look at HttpClient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not ideal to use MVC 4 as a restful host because it is designed to be rendered to HTML.

You will instead want to use Web API. It's designed to be consumed by clients.

You can abstract the logic from the MVC project to a shared project and re-use the functions for the Web API.

Here is a great article about writing a client to interact with Web API: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: Can I combine the two together? Have some MVC controllers as well as web api controllers in the same MVC application?

Comment: Yes, you can. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677745/mixing-web-api-and-asp-net-mvc-pages-in-one-project