# Configure routes for MVC and API in same project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-apicontroller

I just merged an existing API project into another existing MVC project. The API controllers have the same name as the MVC controllers but they're in 2 different namespaces (MyApp.Web.MyController and MyApp.API.MyController, respectively).

Now, I don't really know how to configure the routes so that I can access the API controllers :(

I read this post : [Mixing Web Api and ASP.Net MVC Pages in One Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677745/mixing-web-api-and-asp-net-mvc-pages-in-one-project) and would like the achieve what @Mike Wasson suggested there, but I don't know how to configure the routes.

This is what I currently have in RouteConfig.cs:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =  UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Skimpiest way to create new project in vs with API and mvc. You will be able to see how to configure both

Comment: Thank you! I added the WebApiConfig.cs to the MVC project and added a call to it from Global.asax.cs. That seems to do it for now :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you already have it working, but should you ever wish to use your API controllers in an area, you can enable it simply by adding an additional route.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultAreaApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}


// Application_Start

GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

Comment: Well, somehow I managed to get ONE action to work, and all of the other actions return 404 error. All of these actions (in the same controller) used to work when they were in their old API project. I've looked everywhere to see what's causing it but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I have what you showed there, but only one action works. All other actions return 404 Not Found with this long XML message. I'm so baffled.

Comment: What I found is the actions that work have simple parameters (e.g. /api/MyController/WorkingAction/Parameter).

All other actions end up with 404 Not Found (e.g. /api/MyController/NotWorkingAction)

Comment: I posed a separate question since it might be a different issue than this question.

Comment: Hi got some family round. Will have to take a look shortly.

Comment: Can you show the code you use to call these methods (javascript?) and a working example of a method and an invalid one?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I found the issue and posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591888/web-api-routing-only-actions-with-a-uri-parameter-work?noredirect=1#comment38099447_24591888