# Web API Routing - Only actions with a URI parameter work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing, asp.net-apicontroller

I had a web API project that was working fine. I merged it with an MVC project, and now only the actions with a URI parameter work. All other actions end up with a 404 Not Found where even the controller is not found.

Here's what I have in WebApiConfig (standard stuff):

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }        
}
```

Here is the controller class:

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/WikiPlan")]
public class WikiPlanController : ApiController
```

Here's the action that works:

```
http://localhost:2000/api/WikiPlan/SearchWikiPlans/baby
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
[Route("SearchWikiPlans/{keyword}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(List<WikiPlanSearchResultViewModel>))]
public IHttpActionResult SearchWikiPlans(string keyword)
```

Here's one that doesn't work (which used to work when it was in its own project):

```
http://localhost:2000/api/WikiPlan/TopWikiPlans
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
[Route("TopWikiPlans")]
[ResponseType(typeof(List<TopWikiPlan>))]
public IHttpActionResult TopWikiPlans()
```

I don't know what is wrong. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Show us the class declaration please,

Comment: What is the URL you claimed did not work?

Comment: Yes the controller class

Comment: I tested by adding a string parameter to TopWikiPlans action and it worked. So it seems it wants a parameter for some reason.

Comment: Why don't you just use a POST request instead of a GET?

Comment: It's meant to be a GET action. Changing it to POST ends up with the same 404 error though.

Comment: Is the class that is working inheriting from ApiController or just Controller? Your MVC controller classes should inherit Controller and your API ones need to be using ApiController.

Comment: @swestfall: Yes the class declaration is in the post. It inherits from ApiController.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to this Route Debugger tool (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/04/04/debugging-asp-net-web-api-with-route-debugger.aspx), I was able to trace the broken URL and figured out the issue.

Turned out the Framework was matching the broken URL against the MVC route rather than my API routes. So I moved the call to register the API routes on top of the MVC route in Global.asax, and it is now matched correctly.