# Why isn't my ASP.NET API route being called, is my URL not correct?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a new ASP.NET MVC 5 application.
I added an /api folder in my controllers folder and added a MVC2 API controller.

My global.asax has:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
```

My controller looks like:

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("User")] 
    public IToken GetUser()
    {
        return new User();
    }
}
```

Now I get a 404 resource cannot be found error when I go to:

```
http://localhost:53323/api/users/user
http://localhost:53323/api/users/getuser
```

What could the problem be?

**Update**

My MVC route config:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

My API route config:

```
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        //config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        //    name: "DefaultApi",
        //    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        //    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        //);

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Can you post the code in your RouteConfig ?

Comment: Have you changed the `WebApiConfig.cs` file fom `App_Start` folder?

Comment: @Ghukas see above for my webapi config.

Comment: Do you have an mvc controller with the same name under the same namespace as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677745/mixing-web-api-and-asp-net-mvc-pages-in-one-project?

Comment: This is a new solution, I have 1 other MVC controller HomeController

Comment: But are there in the same namespace? Actually I think @CleverHuman in the question I linked has a good point apart from the accepted answer itself

Comment: I would move them to a new namespace, I reckon there's a class there even if the mvc controller doesn't share the name

Comment: @mitomed yes I added a .Api to the namespace, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are missing correct registration in your `Application_Start()`.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration); // This should be above the default route registration.

    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    //GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); // Remove this line.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it turns out it was the order of my routes.  I kept the line ```GlobalConfiguration ... ``` but I just put it above the RouteConfig line.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I also have just checked it. Only the order makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) on your controller and action methods.

**Example**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/users")]
public class UsersController : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("user")]
    public IToken GetUser()
    {
        return new User();
    }
}
```