# Can i use Api controller and controller in same project? i'm using MVC5, web api 2 and asp.net identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity-2

I am very new to **MVC**, My requirement is to develop application using **Web Api 2** ,**Asp.net identity** ,**Entity framework code first method**. Can i put my web api and mvc in same project? can i generate api controller and controller from single model class using identity?  I did a lot of search for this but i din't get perfect solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes. You can select both mvc, api for one project.

Comment: Can i add both Api controller and controller? i'm using Asp.net identity.

Comment: Yes, of course,  for one project you can have both controller and api controller. They are inherited from different classes. i.e. Controller and ApiController.

Comment: @joydesigner Can we have one model class for both Controller and ApiController?

Comment: what is it you are actually having issues with? you said you "didn't get a perfect solution", which implies that you tried some things that didn't give the result you wanted.  You don't explain any of that in this question, however.

Comment: Hi @AndrewCounts i'm doing exactly like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677745/mixing-web-api-and-asp-net-mvc-pages-in-one-project . Is it need to create two models for both Api controller and MVC controller or one is enough for two?

Comment: You can use the same Model Class for both types of controllers, yes.